# Recording time periods of repeated events

Tags: r

I have a dataset where one column records seconds and the others record current players on the field. So for example , it looks like ,

```
       Time.sec.       MTL1                MTL2             MTL3
          1    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
          2    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
          3    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
          4    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
          5    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
          6    11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER 14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC 31-G CAREY PRICE
```

There are about 10 players but only 3 can be there at any given time. If a player joins at MTL1 he could leave at some unspecified time in the future and return in say any of the 3 MTL's.

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this that covers each players time periods inside.

```
          Player             ShiftStart ShiftEnd
 11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER          1        9
 11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER         50       64
 11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER        100      107
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT : added sample dput

```
sample <-   structure(list(Time.sec. = 1:75, MTL1 = c("11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", "11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN"), MTL2 = c("14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", 
    "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", "15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", "22-R DALE WEISE", 
    "22-R DALE WEISE"), MTL3 = c("31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", "26-D JEFF PETRY", 
    "26-D JEFF PETRY"), MTL4 = c("67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", 
    "67-L MAX PACIORETTY", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", 
    "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE", "31-G CAREY PRICE"
    ), MTL5 = c("76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS", 
    "51-C DAVID DESHARNAIS"), MTL6 = c("79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", 
    "79-D ANDREI MARKOV", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", 
    "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "76-D P.K. SUBBAN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", 
    "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN", "74-D ALEXEI EMELIN"), TOR1 = c("2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "2-D MATT HUNWICK", 
    "2-D MATT HUNWICK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK"), TOR2 = c("3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", "3-D DION PHANEUF", 
    "3-D DION PHANEUF", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES"), TOR3 = c("19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", "19-R JOFFREY LUPUL", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", 
    "21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", 
    "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON", "36-D SCOTT HARRINGTON"), TOR4 = c("23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", "23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", "28-R BRAD BOYES", 
    "28-R BRAD BOYES", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI"), TOR5 = c("42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", "42-C TYLER BOZAK", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "43-C NAZEM KADRI", 
    "43-C NAZEM KADRI", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER"), TOR6 = c("45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", 
    "45-G JONATHAN BERNIER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER", 
    "51-D JAKE GARDINER", "51-D JAKE GARDINER")), .Names = c("Time.sec.", 
    "MTL1", "MTL2", "MTL3", "MTL4", "MTL5", "MTL6", "TOR1", "TOR2", 
    "TOR3", "TOR4", "TOR5", "TOR6"), row.names = c(NA, 75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I dont feel like there is any way to get from your sample data to your desired output. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example, preferably using `dput`

Comment: Done, I put about 75 observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that avoids using for loops. I created a simple generic shift data.frame for testing.

```
players <- c("Player 1", "Player 2", "Player 3", "Player 4")
times <- 1:10
spot1 <- c(rep('Player 1', 5), rep('Player 2', 5))
spot2 <- c(rep('Player 2', 1), rep('Player 3', 2), rep('Player 4', 6),rep('Player 1',1))
shift_df <- data.frame(times, spot1, spot2)
shift_df
```

The player_on_ice function returns a logical vector indicating the player was on the ice at a give time point.

```
player_on_ice <- function(shift_df, player_name) {
    apply(shift_df, 1, function(x) {is.element(player_name, x)}
)}
```

The function shift_calculator takes the shift data.frame above and a player name and calculates their shifts. It relies on the `rle` function to keep track of when the player's on the ice and for how long.

```
shift_calculator <- function(shift_df, player_name) {
    on_ice <- player_on_ice(shift_df, player_name)
# check to see if player entered
    if (sum(on_ice) > 0) {
        # rle = 'running length encoding' 
        # returns values which indicates when player is on/off ice and
        # how long they were on or off
        shifts <- rle(on_ice)
        # use cumsum to see they switch from on/off
        switches <- c(0, cumsum(shifts$lengths))
        # use lapply to find when they were on/off
        shifts <- lapply(1:length(shifts$values), function(x) {
            if (shifts$values[x]) {
                data.frame(shiftStart=switches[x]+1, shiftEnd=switches[x+1])
            } else {
                NULL
            }})
    player_df <- do.call(rbind, shifts)
    data.frame(player=player_name, player_df)
    }
}
```

Iterating over player names then produces your final data frame with player name and shift beginnings and ends.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(players, function(x) shift_calculator(shift_df, x)))
```

Comment: This is pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

So, I *think* this works. I had a simpler solution but I was afraid of the situation where a player leaves the game, then re-enters the game in the same position (say player 1 leaves MTL1, then returns to MTL1 later). I created a new variable GSI (game-state-identifier) that starts at 1 then increases each time a game-state changes (player leaves or enters, etc). This *should* avoid screwy behavior by `summarise` since I am using it with `min` to give the start time, and `max` to give the end time. Without GSI and given the situation that I am worried about above, I think `min` would give the start of the first shift at MTL1 and `max` would give the end of the second shift at MTL1, and thus not recognize that those are two distinct shifts. Let me know if something doesn't work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#you will have to change gather_cols to suit your needs. It should be all columns in your
#data except Time.sec.
long<-sample %>% gather(pos, player, gather_cols = MTL1:TOR6)

long$GSI<-1
num<-1

## this might be a little slow if you have a lot of players.
for(i in 1:nrow(long)-1){
  if(isTRUE(all.equal(long[i,]$pos, long[i+1,]$pos)) &&
     isTRUE(all.equal(long[i,]$player, long[i+1,]$player))){
    long[i+1,]$GSI<-num
    }
  else {
    num<-num+1
    long[i+1,]$GSI<-num
  }
}

long %>% group_by(player, pos, GSI) %>% 
  summarise(shiftStart = min(Time.sec.), shiftStop = max(Time.sec.)) 

                    player   pos   GSI shiftStart shiftStop
                     (chr) (chr) (dbl)      (int)     (int)
1   11-R BRENDAN GALLAGHER  MTL1     2          1        46
2      14-C TOMAS PLEKANEC  MTL2     4          1        36
3   15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN  MTL1     3         47        75
4   15-L TOMAS FLEISCHMANN  MTL2     5         37        46
5       19-R JOFFREY LUPUL  TOR3    22          1        37
6         2-D MATT HUNWICK  TOR1    18          1        50
7  21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK  TOR1    19         51        75
8  21-L JAMES VAN RIEMSDYK  TOR3    24         43        50
9          22-R DALE WEISE  MTL2     6         47        75
10     23-C SHAWN MATTHIAS  TOR3    23         38        42
..                     ...   ...   ...        ...       ...
```

Comment: Yes, this def works, although its a bit slow with many observations. Great job though.